# Azure proximity search with exact phrases?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to use the Azure proximity search with two phrases. It works. For example:

```
"unit test"~2 // returns all occurrences of unit and test within two words.
```

However, how can I use an exact phrase in proximity? For example I need to find matches of "unit test" within 5 words of story. The following does not work:

`""unit test" story"~5`

Also `"unit test story"~5` does not return the correct matches.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your query into two parts

1. contains "unit test"
2. "test" is within 5 words of "story"

So the query would become `search="unit test" AND "test story"~5`.